# Extract text from selected tags with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract text from **th** tags in a table so I can print a list of metro stations from a table in a Wikipedia page. I only need text from a certain table (there are two of them in the page)

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_London_Underground_stations"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

stations_table = soup.find("table", class_= "wikitable sortable plainrowheaders")
stations_table

for i in soup.find_all('th', stations_table):
    print(i.text)
```

I can get the table stored in the `stations_table` variable but cannot print the text in `th` tags within the `wikitable sortable plainrowheaders` table. While it does print the station name, it also prints the headers:

*Station
Local authority
Zone(s)[†]
Opened[4]
Main lineopened
Usage[5]*

How can I filter those out?

Comment: code works for me - it displays all stations and more. Maybe you should create more complex search - first all `tr` and next `th` in every `tr`

Comment: Works for me too. What error or unexpected result are you getting?

Comment: why do you use the `lxml`parser and not the `html.parser`? otherwise it also works for me.

Comment: Apologies folks, it was not clear (edited the question): the printed list starts with the headers of the table which I want to filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows all `th` in table - not only stations but also headers like `Stations`, `Lines`

To skip it I search all `tr`, skip first row and then I search `th` in every row

```
for i in stations_table.find_all('tr')[1:]
    print(i.find('th').text.strip())
```

---

Full code

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_London_Underground_stations"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

stations_table = soup.find("table", class_= "wikitable sortable plainrowheaders")

for i in stations_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    print(i.find('th').text.strip())
    #print(i.th.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in soup.find_all('th', stations_table):
```

searches for all the table headings and the table rows. What can be done for this, is to extract all the rows and start printing from the second row (ignoring the title's row) as below

```
for i in stations_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    print(i.find('th').text)
```